# Facebook SDK returns nothing but the Graph API explorer does

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

I have a fql query:

```
{"e426262700718049":"SELECT name, start_time, location, creator, pic_square FROM event WHERE eid=426262700718049","c426262700718049":"SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT creator FROM #e426262700718049)"}
```

In the Graph Api Explorer it works totally fine, but the sdk just return empty array. With different queries it works totally fine.

That's how I implemented it:

```
public function mquery($queries)
{
    $params = array(
            'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
            'queries' => $queries
    );
    return $this->getFb()->api($params);
}
```

Any idea? :)

Comment: Be sure in Graph Explorer to select the same application as you issuing the query with SDK. The results should be same if not file a bug!

Comment: thanks i didnt know about this possibility. but that wasnt the problem, i tried it with 3 different apps and they always returned the expected data :/

Comment: i just changed the app in my sdk configs, but it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to permissions, you probably not authorized the user while trying to retrieve that data with SDK.

Your query returns empty data-set **for me** with both Graph API and Graph Explorer, for you it returning data that isn't available to unauthorized users (which is probably the case for query with SDK).

If you'll call this without `access_token` at all you will get an exception, but with SDK usage application `access_token` is used by default. Just be sure to authorize the user prior querying to get correct results.

BTW, you can use Graph API for the same work instead of old rest call:

```
$fb->api('/fql', array('q'=>'FQL QUERY OR MULTIQUERY'));
```

Comment: hey thanks alot, it was a mistake problem of the sdk, so i did it by my own :)